# Is there any generic method for smart pointers and raw pointers?

Tags: c++, generics, methods, smart-pointers

I have a question about c++ template.

```
template <class Container>
void tryTriggers(const Container& entities)
{
  for (Container::const_iterator ent = std::begin(entities);ent != std::end(entities); ++ent)
  {
    if ((*ent)->isReadyForTriggerUpdate() && (*ent)->isAlive())
    {
      for (TriggerList::const_iterator trg = std::begin(_triggers);trg != std::end(_triggers); ++trg)
      {
         //Try(..) is a method takes *entity(entity's pointer) for parameters.
         //But my container was implemented with unique_ptr. 
         //ex) vector<unique_ptr<entity>> v;
         //So I used get() method for acquire raw pointer.

        (*trg)->Try((*ent).get());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code is template member function for some containers.

It only works with class witch have `isReadyForTriggerUpdate()` and `isAlive()` in it.

`Try(..)` is a method takes `*entity(entity's pointer)` for parameters.

In my case, I use `unique_ptr` int containers so I have to use `get()` method for get raw pointer.

The function doesn't make any problems but.. if I use some container with raw pointers like

```
vector <entity*> v;
```

then it will make problem.

**Question:**
I want to make it more generic so that it can works with raw pointers and smart pointers. Is there any solution about this?

In **STL**, there is `std::begin(con)` for solve problems related with iterating problem in `con.begin()`. So I expect some generic method like

```
std::begin(con)
```

for above problem.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you are rolling with a compiler that supports it, you should replace `TriggerList::const_iterator` with the `auto` keyword and save yourself the effort of typing and reading that huge identifier.

Answer (score 3):

Asides from @Slava's quite correct answer, you can, in general, always write a template function and specialize it for a raw pointer:

```
template<class T>                                                                                                                           
auto find_address_of(T &&p) -> decltype(p.get())
{
    return p.get();
}

template<typename T>
T *find_address_of(T *p)
{
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you take address of dereferenced pointer instead of calling `std::unique_ptr::get()` that should work in both cases:

```
(*trg)->Try(&**ent);
```

Comment: Nice answer <padding>

Answer (score 0):

```
(*ent).get()
```

Since I don't know anything about the rest of your program, I assume this is the only line that prevents your function from working: `get` is a member function of smart pointers but it can't be used with raw pointers. There are two solutions I see that could solve this:

**Solution 1**

Make your `Try` function work with smart pointers as well as raw pointers. For example:

```
class A
{
    public:
        template <class SmartPointer>
        void Try(const SmartPointer& pointer)
        {
            Try(pointer.get());
        }

        void Try(entity* pointer)
        {
            /* Your code here */
        }
}
```

**Solution 2**

If you can't change the class that's being used then you can make a few functions to convert the abstract type you're working on to a raw pointer. One function for smart pointers and one for raw pointers.

```
template <class SmartPointer>
typename SmartPointer::element_type* getRawPointer(Pointer const& p)
{
    return p.get();
}

template <typename T>
T* getRawPointer(T* p)
{
    return p;
}
```

Where `SmartPointer::element_type` is the type used by the smart pointer (`int` for a `std::unique_ptr<int>`). Note that you have to declare it as `typename SmartPointer::element_type` to tell the compiler that this is indeed a type.

**Edit:** Changed `SmartPointer::pointer` to `SmartPointer::element_type*` to make it work with newer smart pointers.